# Hadoop RAID implementation

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

During Hadoop RAID installation, if I modify hdfs-site.xml with reference to http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HDFS-RAID ,

I am not able to access to localhost:50030 and 50070. How to resolve this?

Comment: 50030 and 50070 are jobtracker and namenode web interface port. Did you started the these daemons? Any error there?

Comment: There was no error and all the daemons were started. Is it possible to implement RAID in pseudo-distributed mode?

Comment: RAID should work for pseudo mode. I suggest you do a netstat to double check the ports are actually used.